# What are the Best Free HP QTP / UFT Advanced eLearning Training Videos & Tutorials?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, training, qtp-11.0, uft-12.52

I am new to HP QTP / UFT Automation tool. Could you please suggest some free good websites that provide elearning, training, tutorials, and videos for mastery of HP's QTP software.

What is QTP?

HP’s Quick Test Professional (QTP) is a software that facilitates Automation Testing for software applications – Functional and Regression testing to be more specific. QTP comes with a user interface that can be considered an Integrated Development environment (IDE) for the test itself. The IDE has various features that aid the tester to develop a comprehensive script which would successfully validate the purpose of the test. All these features will be discussed in detail as we proceed through the series of these articles.

Some of the important aspects of QTP:

- It uses VB Script as its scripting language. (A scripting language is one that gets interpreted at runtime)
- QTP runs only in a windows environment.
- The current version of QTP / UFT is 14.00 Released January 27, 2017
- Former software division of Hewlett Packard Enterprise is now part of Micro Focus
- The technologies it supports are Web, Java.Net, SAP, Oracle, Siebel, PeopleSoft, Web Services, and many major languages. Although some of the older versions don’t support all the technologies listed.
- Get a 60 day trial of UFT at https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/products/unified-functional-automated-testing/free-trial

Thanks! :)

Comment: Since there is no one answer for this, I have converted it to CW.

Comment: I found some good video tutorials on uDemy.com for $5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SoftwareTestingHelp.com now has a Free QTP / UFT training series comprised of 27 detailed videos Last Updated: "February 7, 2018". This online free QTP training article series is designed for beginners as well as advanced users. Check it out:

[27 HP Quick Test Professional (QTP) Training Tutorials by SoftwareTestingHelp.com](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/qtp-quicktest-professional-tutorial-1/)

QTP Introduction:

- Tutorial #1 –  Introduction to QuickTest Professional (QTP)
- Tutorial #2 –  Working with QTP Keyword View and Expert view
- Tutorial #3 –  Adding Standard Steps From Keyword View
- Tutorial #4 –  Conditional & Loop Statements in Keyword View
- Tutorial #5 –  Moving Steps and Dealing with Breakpoints
- Tutorial #6 –  Understanding QTP Record and Run Settings
- Tutorial #7 –  How QTP Identify Objects Uniquely? (Must Read)
- Tutorial #8 –  Recording Modes, Object Spy and Repositories

Learn VB Scripting:

- Tutorial #9 –  VBScript Tutorials – A complete guide
- Tutorial #10 – VBScript Basics to learn QTP – Tutorial 2

QTP Checkpoints:

- Tutorial #11 –  Use of Password Encoder and Active Screen
- Tutorial #12 – Expert View, Step Generator and Checkpoints
- Tutorial #13 – Inserting Standard and Image Checkpoint
- Tutorial #14 – Inserting Bitmap and Text Checkpoints in Tests
- Tutorial #15 – Using Text Area, Table, and Page Checkpoints
- Tutorial #16 – XML, Accessibility, and Database Checkpoints

Test Automation Frameworks:

- Tutorial #17 – Automation Frameworks Part-1 (Must Read)
- Tutorial #18 – Test Automation Frameworks Part-2

Enhance Your Tests:

- Tutorial #19 – Parameterization in QTP Part-1
- Tutorial #20 – Parameterization in QTP Part-2
- Tutorial #21 – Actions and Function Libraries
- Tutorial #22 – Using QTP Object Repositories
- Tutorial #23 – Smart Object Identification & Test Result Analysis
- Tutorial #24 – Virtual Objects and Recovery Scenarios
- Tutorial #25 – Descriptive Programming

Test Your Understanding:

- QTP Interview Questions and Answers part 1
- QTP Interview Questions and Answers part 2

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Free HP UFT/QTP (Quick Test Professional) Tutorials by Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial.html)

Key things to remember include:

- Object identification process of QTP (HP UFT) is the core of its automation technology. Understanding the object identification process of QTP is key to becoming successful automation engineer. Pay attention to following lessons.
- Parameterization enables you to run the same QTP test for different test data. Checkpoints adjudicate the pass or fail status to your automation tests.
- The biggest challenge in automation is recognizing GUI objects and manipulating those objects. QTP provides a range of tools like smart identification, ordinal identifiers, to deal with these challenges.
- The goal of QTP automation is to run the test scripts unattended 24X7. But things can go wrong. A robust automation script should be able to handle any exceptions that may arise during script execution. Recovery scenarios will check and fix any error that occur during the automation of the script.
- A frame work is a set of guideline for test automation which when followed during automation scripting produce beneficial outcomes like increase code re-usage, higher portability , reduced script maintenance cost, etc. Let’s study different types of frameworks.
- API are becoming very popular since it is time efficient, language independent, have easy GUI integration. QTP gives you a broad spectrum of features to do API testing.

Full Syllabus Details include:

- Record & Run Settings | Recording the Script
- Object Identification  (Must Watch)
- Understanding Expert View
- Understanding Recorded Script
- Replay | Run Settings
- Test Results for QTP
- Parametrization
- Checkpoints - Standard CheckPoints
- OutPut Values
- If & Else Loop
- Reporter.Report Event | Results Formatting
- Actions
- SMART Identification
- Object Property Modification
- Ordinal Identifiers
- Local Object Repository
- Develop Script in EXPERT View
- Recording Modes in QTP
- User Defined Functions
- Transactions
- Recovery Scenarios
- Optional Step
- GetROProperty | Object Spy
- Descriptive Programming - Part 1
- Test Automation Frameworks - (This is an Article not a Video)
- Creating Automation Frameworks with QTP
- Definite Guide to QTP Certification
- Business Process Testing(BPT)
- Using Excel with QTP
- Mobile Testing with QTP
- Environment Variable in QTP
- API Testing with QTP
- QTP Interview Questions
- QTP Quiz

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on this a bit more? What is the site's purpose, and how it relates to QTP?

Comment: @corsika,,, The [www.guru99.com]site purpose is to give free education for all,and for the beginner ,who got little or no automation experience in QTP,,this site will help for begginners...

Comment: @Kotla, Thanks for your response! Direct link @ http://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

There are many websites and forum that offer information for all experience levels. Since you're looking for a website with videos, this is the only one that I know of: http://motevich.blogspot.in/

However, there are other websites as well which may aid you in learning QTP. This is the list of sites from  http://www.automationrepository.com/qtp-blogs/

---

[www.learnqtp.com](http://www.learnqtp.com/)

[relevantcodes.com](http://relevantcodes.com/)

[www.advancedqtp.com](http://www.advancedqtp.com/)

[www.advancedqtp.com/forums/](http://www.advancedqtp.com/forums/)

[www.learnqtp.com/forums/](http://www.learnqtp.com/forums/)

[knowledgeinbox.com/](http://knowledgeinbox.com/)

[www.sqaforums.com/](http://www.sqaforums.com/postlist.php?Cat=0&Board=UBB20)

[www.motevich.blogspot.com/](http://www.motevich.blogspot.com/)

[www.quicklearnqtp.com](http://www.quicklearnqtp.com)

[www.qtp10.com/](http://www.qtp10.com/)

[www.joecolantonio.com/](http://www.joecolantonio.com/)

[www.learnqtp.info/](http://www.learnqtp.info/)

[bharath-marrivada.blogspot.com/](http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.com/)

[venkyqtp.blogspot.com/](http://venkyqtp.blogspot.com/)

[qtp.blogspot.com/](http://qtp.blogspot.com/)

[guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial.html](http://www.guru99.com/quick-test-professional-qtp-tutorial.html)

[quicktestprofessional.wordpress.com/](http://quicktestprofessional.wordpress.com/)

[groups.google.com/group/MercuryQTP](http://groups.google.com/group/MercuryQTP)

Comment: I'm looking for the top 3 options not all the options lol. What are the top 3?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up signing up for the best of the HP UFT Classes available on UDemy for only $5 on sale:  ["HP UFT / QTP 14.00 (Latest Version)"](https://www.udemy.com/hp-uft-qtp-latest-version/learn/v4/overview)

I found it very helpful, detailed, it's watchable on mobile, and it comes with a certificate of completion!

Course Details:

- Lectures: 41
- Video: 5 hours
- Skill level: Beginner to Advanced Level
- Lifetime access
- Available on iOS and Android
- Certificate of Completion

Course Content:

- Section: 1 - Setup, Recording Tests, Running Tests
- Section: 2 - Parameterization
- Section: 3 - Checkpoints
- Section: 4 - Output Value
- Section: 5 - Objects
- Section: 6 - Recording Types
- Section: 7 - Actions